# PushNotificationIOS.getInitialNotification() always returns null when the app is not working

Tags: react-native-push-notification

`PushNotificationIOS.getInitialNotification()` always returns null when the app is in dead state.

I'm using react native 59.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Try use this solution https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/333#issuecomment-278006766